# INSERT from UNION of 2 selects?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say you have a non-relational table `Persons` that is filled with badly formatted data:

Persons:

```
id       name       city        state      country
('1', 'username1', 'Cityville', 'Alabama', 'USA')
('1', 'username1', 'Cityville', 'Alabama', 'USA')
('2', 'username2', 'Cityville', 'Alabama', 'USA')
('2', 'username2', 'Cityville', 'Alabama', 'USA')
('3', 'username3', 'Knoxville', 'Tennessee', 'USA')
```

and you have a table setup that relates location id's to city state country tuples:

Location:

```
loc_id    city        state    country
 (1,     'Cityville', 'Alabama', 'USA')
 (2,     'Knoxville', 'Tennessee', 'USA')
```

And you want to insert this data into Clean_Persons where Clean_Person the first row is `Persons.id` and second row is the result of the city state country lookup from Location

Clean_Persons

```
user_id    loc_id
(1,        1)
(2,        1)
(3,        2)
```

My attempt:

```
INSERT INTO Clean_Persons (user_ID, Loc_ID)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(USER_ID) FROM Persons
UNION
SELECT loc_ID FROM Location L JOIN Persons P ON (
   L.city = P.city AND
   L.state = P.state AND
   L.country = P.country 
);
```

Comment: So what did not work with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to do a UNION ALL here I think it should be something like this...

```
INSERT INTO Clean_Persons (user_ID, Loc_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(P.USER_ID),   L.loc_ID 
FROM Location L JOIN Persons P 
ON (
   L.city = P.city AND
   L.state = P.state AND
   L.country = P.country 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `UNION`, but rather just a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO Clean_Persons (Id, Name, Loc_Id)
SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(P.Id), P.Name, L.Loc_Id
FROM Persons P 
    JOIN Location L ON P.City = L.City 
        AND P.State = L.State 
        AND P.Country = L.Country
```

Given the duplicated data in the `Persons` table, I'd also use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicates.  With this said, is it possible the same person could have multiple addresses? If so, consider adding another table for `PersonLocations` as this current query would insert duplicate records in the `Clean_Persons` table.  This will help keep your database normalized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just `INNER JOIN` without `UNION` here:

```
INSERT INTO Clean_Persons (user_ID, Loc_ID)
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS user_id, l.loc_id
FROM 
  persons p INNER JOIN locations l ON l.city = p.city AND
                                      l.state = p.state AND
                                      l.country = p.country
```